# Appending to csv title

Tags: python, list, file, csv, file-io

I'm entering my data into a .csv file and I'm doing it like this:

```
my_list = ['ip5v', 'ip7.5', 'ip10v', 'ip12.5v', 'ip15v', 'ip17.5v', 'ip20v']
a = ipen('csv_fi.csv', 'a')
b = csv.writer(a)
b.writerow(('SerialNo','ip5v', 'ip7.5', 'ip10v', 'ip12.5v', 'ip15v', 'ip17.5v', 'ip20v'))
```

Then my .csv doc has proper columns as:

```
SerialNo,ip5v, ip7.5v, ip10v, ip12.5v, ip15v, ip17.5v, ip20v
```

I tried to make the title more generic and did:

```
b.writerow(('SerialNo', my_list))
```

and got Header as:

```
SerialNo,"['ip5v', 'ip7.5v', 'ip10v', 'ip12.5v', 'ip15v', 'ip17.5v', 'ip20v']"
```

Where I went wrong and how should I edit it to make generic like:

```
SerialNo,ip5v, ip7.5v, ip10v, ip12.5v, ip15v, ip17.5v, ip20v
```

Comment: You are passing a two-tuple to `writerow`, did you mean e.g. `b.writerow(['SerialNo']+my_list)`?

Comment: You might also get some benefit from using a `DictWriter` and the corresponding `writeHeader` method. https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter.writeheader